# Unable to reproduce output from skimr vignette

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, skimr

The [skimr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/skimr/vignettes/Using_skimr.html) shows the following example:

```
library(skimr)
skim(iris)

## Skim summary statistics
##  n obs: 150 
##  n variables: 5 
## 
## ── Variable type:factor ─────────────────────────────────────
##  variable missing complete   n n_unique                       top_counts
##   Species       0      150 150        3 set: 50, ver: 50, vir: 50, NA: 0
##  ordered
##    FALSE
## 
## ── Variable type:numeric ────────────────────────────────────
##      variable missing complete   n mean   sd  p0 p25  p50 p75 p100
##  Petal.Length       0      150 150 3.76 1.77 1   1.6 4.35 5.1  6.9
##   Petal.Width       0      150 150 1.2  0.76 0.1 0.3 1.3  1.8  2.5
##  Sepal.Length       0      150 150 5.84 0.83 4.3 5.1 5.8  6.4  7.9
##   Sepal.Width       0      150 150 3.06 0.44 2   2.8 3    3.3  4.4
##      hist
##  ▇▁▁▂▅▅▃▁
##  ▇▁▁▅▃▃▂▂
##  ▂▇▅▇▆▅▂▂
##  ▁▂▅▇▃▂▁▁
```

However, when I run the above code in a ***Jupyter notebook*** I get:

```
## variable type    stat    level   value   formatted
## Sepal.Length numeric missing .all    0.0000000000    0
## Sepal.Length numeric complete    .all    150.0000000000  150
## Sepal.Length numeric n   .all    150.0000000000  150
## Sepal.Length numeric mean    .all    5.8433333333    5.84
## Sepal.Length numeric sd  .all    0.8280661280    0.83
## Sepal.Length numeric p0  .all    4.3000000000    4.3
## Sepal.Length numeric p25 .all    5.1000000000    5.1
## Sepal.Length numeric p50 .all    5.8000000000    5.8
## Sepal.Length numeric p75 .all    6.4000000000    6.4
## Sepal.Length numeric p100    .all    7.9000000000    7.9
## Sepal.Length numeric hist    .all    NA  ▂▇▅▇▆▅▂▂
## Sepal.Width  numeric missing .all    0.0000000000    0
## more rows...
```

How can I get the output as described in the vignette?

Comment: Can you please try skim(iris) %>% print.skim_df()?   Also could you try skim_to_list(iris)?

Comment: For the 1st command, I received the following error: 'could not find function "print.skim_df" '. I got it to work with a slight modification of your code: skim(iris) %>% print(skim_df()). Also, your 2nd suggestion "skim_to_list(iris)" worked well. Thank you.

Comment: Okay ... is it possible you are on R 3.4?  There was another issue with a different function not being found on that version.  We did a release recently to address that one.

Comment: Hi, we have just merged a fix for this in the version 2 branch of the skimr repository. Great if you would try it out. https://github.com/ropensci/skimr